# Kubernetes Solr operator JTS and Polygons jar file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, solr, solrcloud, solr-operator

Is there a way to install/download the library `jts-core` in the folder `SOLR_INSTALL/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/`? As specified in the official guide: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/spatial-search.html#jts-and-polygons-flat

Actually, I tried to put in the middle an `initContainer` that downloads such jar, but I get obviously a `Permission denied` from the Solr container since only root can write on the final solr container.

I tried also to set a `securityContext` only for my `initContainer`, in order to run as root, but that configuration has no effect in the `initContainer`, I think it is not seen by the Solr CRD.

```
podOptions:
  initContainers:
  - name: "install-jts-core"
    image: solr:8.9.0
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'wget -O /opt/solr-8.9.0/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jts-core-1.15.1.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/locationtech/jts/jts-core/1.15.1/jts-core-1.15.1.jar']
    securityContext:   <--- this has no effect on SolrCloud CRD
      runAsUser: 0
```

Another disperate attempt was to set a `podSecurityContext.runAsUser: 0`, so for all containers in the pod, but Solr does not run as `root`, I discarded that option by the way.

Any hint/idea/solution please?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently found a solution that may not be elegant, but works well in any version of Solr image, below a configuration example:

```yaml
podOptions:
  initContainers:
  - name: "install-jts-lib"
    image: solr:8.9.0
    command:
    - 'sh'
    - '-c'
    - |
      wget -O /tmp-webinf-lib/jts-core-1.15.1.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/locationtech/jts/jts-core/1.15.1/jts-core-1.15.1.jar
      cp -R /opt/solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/* /tmp-webinf-lib
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /tmp-webinf-lib
      name: web-inf-lib
  volumes:
  - name: web-inf-lib
    source:
      emptyDir: {}
    defaultContainerMount:
      name: web-inf-lib
      mountPath: /opt/solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib
```

In this example, I create an `emptyDir` volume and attach it in any directory of the `initContainer`, but in the final Solr container I attach it in the `target directory ($SOLR_HOME/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib)`.

This will empty the `../WEB-INF/lib` directory, but since I'm using **the same Solr image**, I can copy the content of `../WEB-INF/lib` (jars and folders) of the `initContainer` at the end.

The effect is that the final container will have all the content it should have had plus the `jts-core-1.15.1.jar` jar.

This works also with other files or libraries you want to bring in the Solr container.

Let me know what do you think of this workaround

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is not about the permission or CRD; the file downloaded by a `install-jts-core` will not be available to other containers because of namespace isolation.

You can create a Dockerfile using solr as the base image and `COPY` the jar to into the image. Then replace `image.repository` solr helm parameter during helm install. This way you run a image with the library pre-installed.